# How can I include content from a class file?

Tags: header-footer, document-classes, documentclass-writing

I have a header (with a logo image) that should be included in every document that uses my document class. The nature of the header is visually complicated, but pretty simple from a code perspective with very little dynamic data (the date that it was generated, the document title, etc).

Should this be included in the class file? Can it be included, such that doing `\documentclass{my_class}` puts that at the top of the page without any additional code in the tex file itself?

I've tried just putting the header into the cls file with a `\begin{document` block, but then the content in the tex document itself does not render. I'm assuming that you can only have one of those, and with the class block rendering, all subsequent are ignored.

Comment: The cls file should not have `\begin{document}`.  What do you mean by "the class block rendering"?

Comment: @Teepeemm I figured as much that it shouldn't have it. But if I want to include an image or some sort of content for every document that uses the class, is that not possible?

Comment: It depends a bit on if you want the header on every page, or just the title page.  For every page, you can load `fancyhdr`.  Only the first page would be harder.  One approach would be for the class file to define `\createHeader`, and then attach that to `AtBeginDocument` or `\maketitle`.